# Quickest way to add minutes and seconds to string formatted 'h:i:s: A'

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetime-format

I'm using [Bootstrap-Timepicker](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/) to collect a time field. The user will select the the start time with the timepicker widget as well as a number of iterations and a time interval. I want to add the selected interval to the time for the given number of iterations.

For example: if the User select 11:40:00 PM and wishes to ad 10 minutes and 15 seconds 4 times, then I need to iterate through the following time values:

1. 11:40:00 PM
2. 11:50:15 PM
3. 12:00:30 AM
4. 12:10:45 AM

Bootstrap-timpicker doesn't provide an easy way to manipulate the time value like this that I know of, and when I get its value it returns a String formatted h:i:s A as in the example above.

I figure there must be an easier way to this than the way I plan to solve this problem currently which would be to parse the value and run if conditions to check to see if the hour or AM/PM roll over. **Should I convert this string to a datetime, and if so, how?** I'm open to other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in the time, with a date, into the JavaScript date object like this:

```
var myDate = new Date('11:40:00 PM 2015-09-23');
```

Then, add minutes

```
myDate.setMinutes(myDate.getMinutes() + 10);
```

Then add seconds

```
myDate.setSeconds(myDate.getSeconds() + 15);
```

And this can be repeated 4 times

You can get the time back out in a format you'd like, just look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

You can also add the time at once, but this is less pretty I think

```
myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime() + 615);
```